# Crop polygon shape from Image using opencv with transparent background

Tags: python, opencv

Looking to crop a  polygon shape from an image, I managed to get the desired shape but with black surroundings, is there a way to get the cropped image as png without the black part ?

```
    points = [[1019,477],[1179,477],[1180,478],[1180,479],[1181,480],[1255,480],[1255,525],[1256,526],[1257,526],[1257,688],[1256,688],[1255,689],[1255,1128],[1256,1129],[1257,1129],[1257,1199],[1256,1199],[1255,1200],[1255,1235],[1256,1236],[1257,1236],[1257,1331],[1256,1331],[1255,1332],[1255,1336],[1256,1337],[1325,1337],[1325,1339],[1326,1340],[1344,1340],[1344,1849],[1061,1849],[1060,1850],[1060,1944],[859,1944],[858,1945],[858,1946],[715,1946],[715,1945],[714,1944],[636,1944],[636,1652],[635,1651],[633,1651],[633,1537],[635,1537],[636,1536],[636,1435],[635,1434],[633,1434],[633,1339],[635,1339],[636,1338],[636,1171],[635,1170],[634,1170],[633,1169],[633,1074],[635,1074],[636,1073],[636,915],[635,914],[633,914],[633,753],[635,753],[636,752],[636,640],[753,640],[754,639],[943,639],[944,638],[944,480],[1017,480],[1018,479],[1018,478],[1019,477]]

    img = cv2.imread('floorplan.jpg')
    mask = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    roi_corners = np.array([points], dtype=np.int32)
    # fill the ROI so it doesn't get wiped out when the mask is applied
    channel_count = img.shape[2]  # i.e. 3 or 4 depending on your img
    ignore_mask_color = (255,)*channel_count
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, roi_corners, ignore_mask_color)

    # apply the mask
    masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)

    # save the result
    cv2.imwrite('img_masked.png', masked_img)
```

here's the source image
[image]
here's the outcome
[image]

Comment: If your image has an alpha channel (4 components), then those pixels are transparent and should take on the background color when displayed.  If not, you can add an alpha channel to it, by converting to 'RGBA" before extracting the array.

Comment: @TimRoberts can you please explain in code how to do that? I'm new to OpenCV